# Test on a Sauce Labs browser that doesn't have Flash installed

Tags: flash, saucelabs

We use Sauce Labs for testing our web applications. We have a page that streams video either using a Flash Player or a HTML 5 player depending upon the capabilities of the user's browser. I'd like to test this page in Sauce Labs (both manually and in automated tests) in a variety of browsers - and particularly, both with and without Flash support.

Is there a way that I can control whether the browser instance Sauce Labs spawns will have Flash or not? I can't see any mention of such an option at https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/test-configuration/ or https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator/#/, but Sauce Labs have mentioned Flash testing a couple of times in their documentation and blog (see http://sauceio.com/index.php/tag/flash-test/ and https://saucelabs.com/docs/flex-getting-started) so it seems like the option ought to exist.

Is there a way to control this that I'm missing?